# Google OAuth CORS issue w/ flask-dance

Tags: flask, oauth, cors, flask-dance

I am setting up a `flask-dance` + `flask-login` project and am having issues with CORS. Specifically, I follow the standard `flask-dance` setup for Google OAuth:

```
google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id=constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope=["profile", "email"]
)
app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint, url_prefix="/b/google_login")
```

On the frontend, I make a `GET` request to `{backend}::/b/google_login/google`, but get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fb%2Fgoogle_login%2Fgoogle%2Fauthorized&scope=profile+email&state=xxx' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5001/b/google_login/google') 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have added the redirect URI (i.e. `/b/google_login/google/authorized` to the redirect-URI whitelist). I am confused why this error is happening - as I am proxying the OAuth redirect through my server.

When I attempt the flow through `window.href = http://localhost:5001/b/google_login/google` - the flow works without issue.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, Google does not want you to do this because it would be a security issue.

Comment: Why would this be a security issue? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The correct way is to redirect to the endpoint, not XHR. The reason it's a security issue is because oauth providers want to prevent clients from automating the login process in a manner they don't control. It's important that the users' browser goes to a google domain and google fully controls the experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could call CORS and pass your Flask object that way. It is as some in the comments have pointed out really janky and unsecure as it would enable CORS for your entire application.

I'm dealing with a similar issue on a different application where I'm passing some data between domains for an emergency alert system. In my case I'm using a jsonpCallback and Ajax to pass data between the domains.